# How to return a html file in c# class library?

Tags: c#, html

I wrote a simple class (.dll) in c#, which generates an html file.

I have to use a return in this class, I do not know how I can do it.

**Code**

```
public class Class1
{
    private void HTMLGenerator()
    {
        string html = "<p>test</p>";

        var xDocument = new XDocument(
            new XDocumentType("html", null, null, null),
            new XElement("html",
                new XElement("head"),
                new XElement("body",
                        XElement.Parse(html)
                    )
                )
           );

        var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
        {
            OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
            Indent = true,
            IndentChars = "\t"
        };

        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(@"C:\Users\\Desktop\test.html", settings))
        {
            xDocument.WriteTo(writer);
        }
    }
}
```

**Html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body><p>test</p></body>
</html>
```

Comment: " I have to use return in this class, but I do not know how I can do it. " - OK; forget about the how for now; what does that *mean to you*? what are you trying *to do*? it isn't clear. Are you talking about writing a method that returns a string? if so: to what purpose? Note: since the method is `private`, isn't currently usable externally...

Comment: I would like to refer to this html file in my main program. Sorry, Marc, I'm still learning programming. Edit: I change my private method to public. :)

Comment: K; but at the moment you're writing to a file; is your intent to "return a string"? or is it "write to somewhere that the caller specifies?" The approach for these is very different.

Comment: I think, that 'return a string' will be OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested but this might help

```
public string HTMLGenerator()
{
    // blah
    using (var sw = new StringWriter()) 
    {
        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(sm, settings))
        {
            xDocument.WriteTo(writer);
        }

        return sw.ToString();
    }
}
```

As noted in the comments

> It is bad idea to construct HTML with XML writer (not as awful as
>   read, but still can produce undesired artefacts like extra new lines
>   at least)

Comment: probably want to make it `public` too, to be consumable

Comment: You may also add comment that it is bad idea to construct HTML with XML writer (not as awful as read, but still can produce undesired artifacts like extra new lines at least)

Comment: Thanks @AlexeiLevenkov

Comment: Thank you, people. I was able to compile this dll file.
I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but how can I write the code in my main program for this dll? I can add references, but I dont know how to write a view this html file and print out.

Comment: This is technically other question, however you can add a reference to the library or dll in Visual studio, in Add -> Reference